# How to left align all my tables in the appendix section? Such that they all start from the exact same left margin

Tags: datatable, latex, overleaf

I want to ensure that all the tables in my appendix start from the same left margin. With my code below I do not get the identical alignments for all my tables. The first table is more to the left compared the second table which is more centered. How do I resolve this uniformly for all my tables in the appendix section?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\label{R1}
\begin{flushleft}
    
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.8cm}{}
        \centering
        
        \footnotesize
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{3}{r}{Dependent Variables: } \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
            & xxx & xxx \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Effect of exposure to hurricane intensity winds}} \\
            \midrule
            
            Max wind speed $\epsilon[64,95)$ knots in the last 1-3 years & xx & xx \\
            & (0.03) & (0.03) \\
            Max wind speed $\epsilon[64,95)$ knots in the last 4-9 years & xx & xx \\
            & (0.04) & (0.03) \\
            Max wind speed $\epsilon[64,95)$ knots in the last 10-20 years & xx & xx \\
            & (0.04) & (0.03) \\
            
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{Observations} & 72654 & 74531 \\   
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.8cm}{}
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{3}{r}{Dependent Variables: } \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
            & xx & xx \\
            
            \midrule
            1 SD mean damaging ($\geq$50 knots) wind in the last 1-3 years & xx & xx \\
            & (0.01) & (0.01) \\
            1 SD mean damaging ($\geq$50 knots) wind in the last 4-9 years & xx & xx \\
            & (0.01) & (0.01) \\ \\
            
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{Observations} & 68,049 & 69,915 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{flushleft}
```

\end{table}

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]